# 2 дива на одном уровне

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть лого и 2 текста. Нужно, чтобы они были в одном диве, но лого всегда улетает вниз. Скрин для понятия. Код ниже.

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 55px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.zagolovok {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Impact;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.shapka {
  height: 250px;
}

.logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 230px
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-sm-none d-md-block">
    <div class="shapka d-none d-sm-block">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-end flex-column ">
        <!-- Правая часть контейнера-->
        <p2 class="p-2 zagolovok box wow center-text fadeInLeft col-4 d-none d-md-block" style="margin-top:10%" data-wow-delay="0.4s"><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> Русская,35 </p2>
        <p1 class=" p-2 zagolovok box wow fadeInLeft col-4 d-none d-md-block" style="margin-top:2%" data-wow-delay="0.4s"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>+79069960426 </p1>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-Left">
        <img src="Logo.png" class="logo p-2  d-none d-md-block " alt="img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Лого спряталось за Навбаром]

Comment: margin-top не предлагать, усугубит адаптацию.

Comment: Видимо опять пятница :-( Смотрю на стрелку и не понимаю что там у неё криво :-(

Comment: Напиши код поподробнее, то гда дадут ответ сразу. Надо кажется тебе `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` использовать